# How to find a prime number with an upperbound and store in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numbers

So I'm trying to find a prime number, and store it in an array. The ones I looked at and searched are somewhat confusing and my teacher's explanation is confusing in it self. His pseudo code is [confusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqQfo.png) and my current code that I have is

```
prime = [False,False]
anumber = int(input("Enter the upper bound number: "))

print("generating all primes between 2 and ", anumber)

j=0
while anumber > j:
    for j in range(2,anumber):
        if(anumber % j ) ==0:
            print(j,"is not prime")
            prime.append(False)
        else:
            print(j,"is prime")
            prime.append(True)
print(prime)
```

I'm new to programming and this is really numbing my head. The output that my teacher had put on his website that he had and the output that I'm getting is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LREL0.png). They're nothing alike, yet I don't understnad what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your teacher's code is implementing a *prime sieve*. Does that ring a bell? Was that mentioned in class at all?

Comment: There are  many differences between the professors algorithm and what you have implemented. Going through your code step by step would be doing your homework for you.

Comment: You aren't following the pseudo-code very closely. For starters, prime is supposed to contain a number of entries equal to the number that the user inputted, and they're all supposed to be initialized to True.

Comment: GregHewgill No he didn't actually, this is news to me @Seaotternerd alright, I redid it [here](http://pastebin.com/69aRcW13) and this was the [output](http://i.imgur.com/qxViTPn.png) It's not printing anything out now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is your `while anumber > j:`, at no point does `j` get incremented so you have an infinite loop.

Next the pseudo code has no need of modulo (`%`) as it is a [prime sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Prime_sieves).
A prime sieve removes all numbers which can't be prime; in the case of your algorithm multiples of prime numbers.

You need to iterate through all the numbers and remove all the multiples of prime numbers. You also should not append True/False but change the marking according to if the number is prime or not.

Please note composite means not prime

The following code is a working prime sieve based on the pseudo code given.

```
upperBound = input("Enter the upper bound number: ")

"""Create a list named prime of booleans, all set to True, for numbers between 0 and the upper bound"""
prime = [True]*(upperBound + 1) #List of booleans all set to True


"""set prime[0] and prime[1] to False"""
prime[0] = False #0 is not prime
prime[1] = False #1 is not prime

print "Generating all primes between 2 and", upperBound

"""let p loop over all values between 2 and the upper bound (inclusive)"""
for p in range(2, upperBound + 1): #Loop through all the values between 2 and the upper bound, inclusive
    print "Checking", str(p)
    if prime[p] == True: #if the number is prime
        k = p + p #k is the first multiple of the prime number
        print " ", str(p), "is prime"
        for x in range(k, upperBound + 1, p): #Iterate through all the multiples of the prime, less than the upper bound
            print " ", str(x), "is not prime"
            prime[x] = False #Mark the multiples as composite

"""The prime list now has a True value for those numbers that are prime"""

"""Generate the result list with a loop adding numbers to the list"""
primeNumbers = []
for x in range(len(prime)): #Iterate through the boolean list
    if prime[x] == True: #if the number is prime
        primeNumbers.append(x) #add it to the list of prime numbers

print primeNumbers
```

This algorithm is not as efficient as it could be because once you reach half of the upper bound  + 1 all the composite numbers have been found. You should also note that this sieve is not suitable for very large upper bounds.

e.g. upper bound = 10

Once p = 6 the multiples (12, 18, 24...) of p are all above the upper bound so you are now wasting processing time as the for loop will not return any numbers.

```
>>> range(12, 11, 6)
[]
>>>
```

So the algorithem can be improved by replacing

```
for p in range(2, upperBound + 1): #Loop through all the values between 2 and the upper bound, inclusive
```

with

```
for p in range(2, (upperBound/2) + 1): #Loop through all the values between 2 and half the upper bound + 1
```

Original version took (for upper bound = 100): 2.39502692223

New version took (for upper bound = 100): 1.88608288765

The main reason for this is that there is less printing done.

Example output for an upper bound of 100 can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Cv9WASzA), this is using the more efficient version.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! I'm still slightly confused about arrays but this clears up some of the clouds...

Comment: @EmmettThorne Your welcome. [Python lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on lists.